# How to read input pin on MCP23017?

Tags: arduino-uno, input, io-expander

I'm working to develop a simple code for MCP23017 that I want to use to run LCD128x64.

I was succeeded to set `IODIRB` as output and blink LED as a test.

Now I want to read the pin state, but I couldn't. Here's my code. I'm using the nice twi library that comes with Wire library.

```
uint8_t mcp23017_read(uint8_t add_reg){
    uint8_t data;
    twi_writeTo(MCP23017_ADD,add_reg,2,1,0);    
    twi_readFrom(MCP23017_ADD,data,1,1);

    return data;
}
```

I've tried this version too:

```
uint8_t *mcp23017_read(uint8_t add_reg){
    uint8_t data[1];
    twi_writeTo(MCP23017_ADD,add_reg,2,1,0);    
    twi_readFrom(MCP23017_ADD,data,1,1);

    return *data;
}
```

==================================================

Here's Arduino call function:

```
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  data = mcp23017_read(GPIOB);
  Serial.println(data);
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: how do you know that you cannot read the pin state?

Comment: I'm connecting the pin with a resistor to 5V or GND.

Comment: here is an example about reading inputs https://tronixstuff.com/2011/08/26/arduino-mcp23017-tutorial/

Comment: Is there a reason why you use TWI but not Wire?

Comment: Yes, I can same like 300 bytes of the flash memory. And I want to learn how to study other people's code. The twi is a very good example. I learned how ISR work and how functions should handle buffered TX/Rx data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how this lib works. But I'm pretty sure that you have to pass a pointer onto the `data` variable into the `twi_readFrom` method.

```
uint8_t mcp23017_read( uint8_t add_reg )
{
    uint8_t data;
    twi_writeTo( MCP23017_ADD, add_reg, 2, 1, 0 );    
    // I inserted an & below
    twi_readFrom( MCP23017_ADD, &data, 1, 1 );

    return data;
}
```

Or in case of the second function:

```
// I removed the star operator
uint8_t mcp23017_read(uint8_t add_reg)
{
    uint8_t data[1];

    twi_writeTo( MCP23017_ADD, add_reg, 2, 1, 0 );    
    // you pass the pointer to the array element 0
    twi_readFrom( MCP23017_ADD, data, 1, 1 );

    // I returned the element 0
    return data[0];
}
```

**Update:**

Just for completeness: The OP found also a failure on the write function. He had posted a separate answer, I voted up to mark it. Because this is the accepted answer, I also copied his post to here for completeness and the readers convenience.

Original post by R1S8K:

> OK, I found a the answer and it was a good lesson in dealing with
>   functions that receives pointers.
>
> I forgot that the writeTo function also receives a pointer and I have
>   to pass an array for both read/write functions.
>
> ```
> void mcp23017_read(uint8_t *add_reg, uint8_t *buffer){
>     twi_writeTo(MCP23017_ADD, add_reg, 1, 1, 1);    
>     twi_readFrom(MCP23017_ADD, buffer, 1, 1);
> }
> ```

Comment: It isn't working ! I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Should I launch a repstart or not ... etc.

Comment: Yep, that's very nice :) Thanks for improving my thread.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found one little mistake in my coding.

I forgot that the `writeTo` function also receives a pointer and I have to pass an array for both read/write functions.

```
void mcp23017_read(uint8_t *add_reg, uint8_t *buffer){
    twi_writeTo(MCP23017_ADD, add_reg, 1, 1, 1);    
    twi_readFrom(MCP23017_ADD, buffer, 1, 1);
}
```